# How to check a single property in a JSON array are all the same

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to determine if a single property in a JSON array are all the same.

This is my JSON:

```json
{
    "project": 1,
    "info": {
        "things": [
            { "thingId": 1, "status": "success" },
            { "thingId": 2, "status": "success" },
            { "thingId": 3, "status": "failure" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Given that JSON payload, I'm trying to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` if:

1. `things` is null/empty - `TRUE` (nothing to check, so we're OK).
2. `things` exists AND has some data ... and *all* the `status` properties equal `"success"` - `TRUE`.
3. else `FALSE`

For this example, lets use this syntax:

```bsh
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://my.api.com/something/here' -Method Get).info.<not sure of the rest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straightforward to me (as long as by "null/empty" you mean an empty array or string, not an empty object).

```
$json = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://my.api.com/something/here' -Method Get
-not $json.info.things -or $json.info.things.status -notcontains 'failure'
```

If you're stuck with PowerShell v2 replace the second clause with

```
@($json.info.things | Select-Object -Expand status) -notcontains 'failure'
```

If there can be states other than `success` and `failure` replace it with something like this:

```
@($json.info.things | ? {$_.status -eq 'success'}).Count -eq $json.info.things.Count
```